# Configuring touch screen monitor

Tags: kde, touch-screen, multi-touch

My brother recently bought a touch screen monitor [Dell S2240T](http://www1.ap.dell.com/in/en/home/22lcd/dell-s2240t/pd.aspx?refid=dell-s2240t&s=dhs&cs=indhs1), I connected it to my laptop using HDMI interface. I'm using OpenSuse 13.2 with latest stable KDE4. Initially monitor display looks blurred, after manually setting monitor frequency to 60Hz, it look better.

1. It recognized proper resolution 1080p but not using full width of
   screen.
2. It is incorrectly recognizing location of touch input (for example if I touch on a folder in dolphin, it opens other folder) . Also multi-touch is not working.
3. Is there any utility to properly calibrate touch screen?

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility available for this, and I'm sure there is more, but the one I'm aware of is called EvTouch. It will allow you calibrate your touch screen. I found the following thread for a different version of opensuse that will hopefully point you in the right direction.

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/429517-Can-t-calibrate-touchscreen